# Search two conditions in the lines on Log in Python

Tags: python

I have same code for count when in the line match two conditions (This code work fine)

```
import csv
import string
f=open('myfile.log','r')
results = [line[31] for line in f.readlines() if (line[31] == "w" and line[35] == "0")]
f.close()
for r in results:
    print r
x = len(results)
print x
```

the problem is when need use 4 numbers in the second conditions example "701"

i use this code but does not work.

```
import csv
import string
f=open('myfile.log','r')
results = [line[31] for line in f.readlines() if (line[31] == "w" and line[41:43] == "701")]
f.close()
for r in results:
    print r
x = len(results)
print x
```

Comment: You forgot quotes around `701`.

Comment: So it was just this typo or there is something else?